# How to include a dynamic library in C++

Tags: c++, libusb

If I search for files that include file *libusb.h*,

```
$grep -r "libusb.h" /usr/local/lib/
```

I get:

> Binary file /usr/local/lib//libusb-1.0.0.dylib matches
>   Binary file /usr/local/lib//libusb-1.0.a matches
>   Binary file /usr/local/lib//libusb-1.0.dylib matches

But when I compile my class I get:

```
test.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'libusb.h' file not found
#include <libusb.h>
```

Now I know this is because the */usr/local/lib* folder isn't properly included. I tried things like the following, etc., but nothing seems to fix it.

```
gcc -lusb test.cpp
C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/lib
export C_INCLUDE_PATH
```

## Update

Thanks to some of the help, I have come up with this command...

```
gcc test.cpp -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lusb-1.0
```

But now I get...

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I tried adding

> -stdlib=libstdc++

But that doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: You're just grepping binary data for libusb.h. You need to change your include paths in order to pick up the actual header file.

Comment: *[grep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep)* searches in the *content* of files, not for *file names*. Are you sure you did not intend to search for files named *libusb.h* in folder */usr/local/lib*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works...

```
gcc -std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++ -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lusb-1.0 -lstdc++ test.cpp
```

You can also switch to [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang). This works:

```
clang++ -std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++ -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lusb-1.0 test.cpp
```

See comments for more information.

Comment: If you actually post the full error message we can tell you what's wrong in the GCC case.

Comment: Will do a bit busy with the holiday will try to add that to the answer.

Comment: And the exact command that gives that error? Try using g++ instead of gcc.

Comment: It is the one I list second in this answer, I will try g++ later but can't gcc compile c++?

Comment: yes it can (`gcc` is just a compiler frontend, it tries to detect the input language through the filename's extension), but `g++`, when called to link, also pulls in the C++ standard library, which `gcc` does not do. If you want to link C++ object code which uses the standard library, you need to add `-lstdc++`. Using `g++` for C++ is just easier `;-)`.

Comment: Good work that does work when I add the -lstdc++. I like to clear the clouds and prevent obscurity even for the sake of convenience.

Comment: using gcc instead of g++ is adding obscurity. What I described might not cut it in all situations and/or all platforms. Do what's right, not what you think is right based on very limited experience.

Comment: Ok but how is it less obscure if it is including other libs by default?

Comment: I invite you to look at the verbose output of gcc and see hoe many libs are linked and what options are passed to ld without you knowing. You don't want to care, trust me. But do as you wish, I'm just trying to save you trouble. Your principle is flawed from the beginning,, that's all I'm saying... I'm not going to try and convince you further.

Answer (score 2):

Including the lib path won't help you here.  The lib path contains the path of the binary files you link with.

You need to find the *include* path which provides the declarations for the exported symbols of the lib that you link against.

A common distribution (not set in stone!), is:

```
lib/       (binaries to link against)
include/   (declarations are here!)
bin/       (.so on *nix or .dll or Windows)
```

Comment: Great so I see what you mean in the folder /usr/local/include/libusb-1.0/ I see the header-file. Could you possibly add the gcc command though (assuming the binaries are as described before). I tried using the gcc -l/usr/local/include/libusb-1.0 test.cpp and that didn't work. Sorry pretty new to all this.

Comment: Alas, linux is not my forte, but isn't it something along the lines of `C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include/libusb-1.0/`?  I am sure someone else will let you know the exact way to do this.

Comment: gcc -I/usr/local/include/libusb-1.0 test.cpp works a little bit better but gives me "ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64"

Answer (score 1):

I may be beating a dead horse here. However I had the same issue and the solutions listed did not work for me. If you are in the same boat, this is what ended up working for me:

`gcc -I /usr/include/libusb-1.0/ -lusb-1.0 example.c`